# JSON array gets split into letters while reading

Tags: javascript, json, get

I am trying to read a JSON response, however when I parse it, it gets split into letters, not JSON objects. Below is my code and the outcome seen when debugging.

Thanks in advance.

```
$.get(sUrl)
  .done(function(results) {
    if (results != null) {
      debugger;
      var resultInJsonFormat = JSON.parse(results);

      // tried this as well
      // var resultInJsonFormat = JSON.parse(results.toString());   
      var resultJsonArray = resultInJsonFormat.TimeEvents;
      var timeEventResults = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < resultJsonArray.length; i++) {
        var resultx = resultInJsonFormat.TimeEvents[i];
      }
    }
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    if (err !== undefined) {
      var oErrorResponse = $.parseJSON(err.responseText);
      sap.m.MessageToast.show(oErrorResponse.message, {
        duration: 6000
      });
    } else {
      sap.m.MessageToast.show("Unknown error!");
    }
  });
```

================ debugger result ================

```
results = "{"TimeEvents":"[{\"timeEventId\":\"5974\",\"empID\":\"00000004\",\"timeEventType\":\"CheckOut\",\"logDate\":\"Oct 16, 2017\",\"logTime\":\"11:00:43 PM\",\"readLogDate\":\"Oct 16, 2017\",\"readlogTime\":\"08:13:55 PM\",\"dayAssignment\":1,\"terminalId\":2,\"origin\":1},{\"timeEventId\":\"5995\",\"empID\":\"00000004\",\"timeEventType\":\"CheckIn\",\"logDate\":\"Oct 17, 2017\",\"logTime\":\"11:45:15 PM\",\"readLogDate\":\"Oct 17, 2017\",\"readlogTime\":\"07:40:41 AM\",\"dayAssignment\":1,\"terminalId\":2,\"origin\":1},{\"timeEventId\":\"10280\",\"empID\":\"00000004\",\"timeEventType\":\"CheckOut\",\"logDate\":\"Oct 24, 2017\",\"logTime\":\"11:45:14 PM\",\"readLogDate\":\"Oct 18, 2017\",\"readlogTime\":\"05:55:43 PM\",\"dayAssignment\":1,\"terminalId\":2,\"origin\":1}]"}"
resultJsonArray = "[{"timeEventId":"5974","empID":"00000004","timeEventType":"CheckOut","logDate":"Oct 16, 2017","logTime":"11:00:43 PM","readLogDate":"Oct 16, 2017","readlogTime":"08:13:55 PM","dayAssignment":1,"terminalId":2,"origin":1},{"timeEventId":"5995","empID":"00000004","timeEventType":"CheckIn","logDate":"Oct 17, 2017","logTime":"11:45:15 PM","readLogDate":"Oct 17, 2017","readlogTime":"07:40:41 AM","dayAssignment":1,"terminalId":2,"origin":1},{"timeEventId":"10280","empID":"00000004","timeEventType":"CheckOut","logDate":"Oct 24, 2017","logTime":"11:45:14 PM","readLogDate":"Oct 18, 2017","readlogTime":"05:55:43 PM","dayAssignment":1,"terminalId":2,"origin":1}]"

iteration i = 0
resultx = "["
iteration i = 1
resultx = "{"
```

Comment: at first glance `results`  is being served back as an escaped string, not a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `results` incorrectly has a string value, not the array you're expecting. Note the double quotes after the first colon.

```
results = "{"TimeEvents":"[{...
```

Iterating over each item in a string will return a character, which is the behaviour you're seeing.

Check the source of the data. Is it returning valid JSON?